# Sampling my samples: What happens to the confidence interval and the average?

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling

I have 25 small images where some pixels contain defects (normal distr). Now I can count for every image the amount of defects and calculate the **average defect per image** with its CI.

Due to time constraints we cannot check every pixel for defects. Therefore we sample the pixels for each, but I'm still interested in the **average defect per image**.

My question is how can I obtain this statistic with a 95% CI for the original problem then?

My idea: (5/200)*1000, with 5 defects found in the sampled 200 pixels and 1000 the total amount of pixels in the image. Is this statistically sound? Because the (5/200) is a statistic in itself..?

Comment: Does it qualify as "salt and pepper" defects?  If so there are textbook "cleaning methods" that can remove the defects.  With that, you then subtract the original from the cleaned, look at the normal quantile plot for the normal component of the distribution, and threshold at its left tail, then count.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The actual image processing is not important for the problem. I would want to know what happens to the statistic (the average) and the confidence interval for such a problem.

The actual problem is that we need to analyse every 'pixel' by a hardware inspection method which takes a lot of time. The result is something like 30 out of 1000 have a defect (assuming 1000 pixels), where the 30 itself is a sample from the population. We want to sample these 1000 te reduce the time for inspection (say 200), a different number is expected to be found < 30. What happens to my CI?